# bash history line editing command replaced inside here doc enclosed by process substitution

Tags: bash, shell

I want to run below bash command with here doc enclosed by process substitution expression.

```
$cat <(cat <<'xx'
1st line
2nd !!
xx
)
```

But the output is as follows. The result suggests that the c-shell style history line editing command !! (last command) is replaced with the corresponding command output(i.e. the last command) and then is executed.

```
$ cat <(cat <<'xx'
> 1st line
> 2nd !!
2nd cat <(cat <<'xx'
1st line
> xx
> )
1st line
2nd cat <(cat <<'xx'
1st line
```

My question is why the history line editing command !! in heredoc is replaced with the last command and executed in the example?

Note that in below 2 examples, the built-in shell variable $$ is NOT interpolated, and the !! command in pure here doc without being enclosed in process substitution is NOT interpolated!

```
$ cat <(cat <<'xx'
> 1st line
> 2nd $$
> xx
> )
1st line
2nd $$

$ cat <<'xx'
> 1st line
> 2nd !!
> xx
1st line
2nd !!
```

Please provide an in-depth explanations on the root cause.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here Documents

This type of redirection instructs the shell to read input from the current source until a line containing only delimiter (with no trailing blanks) is seen.  All of the lines read up to that point are then used as the standard input for a command.

The format of here-documents is:

```
<<[-]word
        here-document
delimiter
```

No parameter and variable expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, or pathname expansion is performed on word. **If any characters in word are quoted, the delimiter is the result of quote removal on word, and the lines in the here-document are not expanded.** If word is unquoted, all lines of the here-document are subjected to  parameter expansion, command substitution, and arithmetic expansion, the character sequence \ is ignored, and \ must be used to quote the characters \, $, and `.

Comment: I know what here doc is. Since EOF is single-quoted, the content of here doc should NOT be expanded, including variable expansion, command substitution,etc.  Maybe history event designator is an exception to this?